# pandas multiply each dataset row by multiple vectors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = {1,2,3
      4,5,6
      7,8,9,
      10,11,12
}

weights={[1,3,3],[2,2,2],[3,1,1]}
```

I want to multiply my df with every line of matrix weights(so I'll have like three different df, one for each vector of weights, and to combine each df by keeping the biggest line of values). Ex:

```
df0=df * weights[0]={1,6,9
                    4,15,18,
                    7,24,27
                    10,33,36
                    } 

df1=df*wieghts[1]={2,4,6,
                   8,19,12,
                   14,16,18,
                   20,22,24
                  }

df2=df*wieghts[2]={3,2,3,
                   12,5,6,
                   21,8,9,
                   30,11,12
                  }
```

and

```
final_df_lines=max{df0,df1,df2}={1,6,9 - max line line from df0, 
                                     4,15,18, - max line from df0, 
                                     7,24,27 - max line from df0, 
                                     10,33,36 - max line from df0, 
                                     }
```

In this example all max were from df0 ... but they could be from any of the three df. Max line is just adding the numbers from the same line..

I need to do this things vectorized(without any loops or if...) how do I do this? is it possible at least? I really need welp :( for 2 days I'm searching the internet to do this... I did not work in python for too long...

Comment: Should be w vector with 4 elements I guess, I mean with shape (3, 4)

Comment: u right, I'll edit right away

Comment: Could you please explain what maxline stands for in this concrete situation?

Comment: To be able to finalize my answer with some max operation.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As question has been updated I had to update too:

You have to align matrices first to be able to make an element-wise matrix operation without using any loop:

```
    import numpy as np

    a = [
         [1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9],
         [10,11,12]
         ]

    weights = [
               [1,3,3], 
               [2,2,2],
               [3,1,1]
              ]

    w_s = np.array( (4 * [weights[0]], 4 * [weights[1]], 4 * [weights[2]]) )
    a_s = np.array(3 * [a])

result_matrix1 = w_s * a_s[0]
result_matrix2 = w_s * a_s[1]
result_matrix3 = w_s * a_s[2]

print(result_matrix1)
print(result_matrix2)
print(result_matrix3)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[ 1  6  9]
  [ 4 15 18]
  [ 7 24 27]
  [10 33 36]]

 [[ 2  4  6]
  [ 8 10 12]
  [14 16 18]
  [20 22 24]]

 [[ 3  2  3]
  [12  5  6]
  [21  8  9]
  [30 11 12]]]
[[[ 1  6  9]
  [ 4 15 18]
  [ 7 24 27]
  [10 33 36]]

 [[ 2  4  6]
  [ 8 10 12]
  [14 16 18]
  [20 22 24]]

 [[ 3  2  3]
  [12  5  6]
  [21  8  9]
  [30 11 12]]]
[[[ 1  6  9]
  [ 4 15 18]
  [ 7 24 27]
  [10 33 36]]

 [[ 2  4  6]
  [ 8 10 12]
  [14 16 18]
  [20 22 24]]

 [[ 3  2  3]
  [12  5  6]
  [21  8  9]
  [30 11 12]]]
```

The solution is `numpy`, but you can do it with `pandas` as well, if you prefer it, of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can try of `concatenat`ing all weights mulitpied columns as one dataframe with `suffix of column` represeting each weight , 
and by `grouping with respect to the weight` it multiplied get max summation of index

with max index weight you can multiply the dataframe

```
df2 = pd.concat([(df*i).add_suffix('__'+str(i)) for i in weights],axis=1).T
                0   1   2   3
0__[1, 3, 3]    1   4   7   10
1__[1, 3, 3]    6   15  24  33
2__[1, 3, 3]    9   18  27  36
0__[2, 2, 2]    2   8   14  20
1__[2, 2, 2]    4   10  16  22
2__[2, 2, 2]    6   12  18  24
0__[3, 1, 1]    3   12  21  30
1__[3, 1, 1]    2   5   8   11
2__[3, 1, 1]    3   6   9   12

#   by grouping with respect to the weight it multiplied, get max index
a = df2.groupby(df2.index.str.split('__').str[1]).apply(lambda x: x.sum()).idxmax()

#  max weights with respect to summation of rows
df['idxmax'] = a.str.slice(1,-1).str.split(',').apply(lambda x: list(map(int,x)))

c    [1, 3, 3]
d    [1, 3, 3]
3    [1, 3, 3]
4    [1, 3, 3]
dtype: object

df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[df.columns.difference(['idxmax'])] * x['idxmax'],1)

   0    1   2
0   1   6   9
1   4   15  18
2   7   24  27
3   10  33  36
```